# Using Static Pattern Rule causes single source change to rebuild all

Tags: c, makefile, compilation, gnu-make

I am trying to fix a Makefile that currently does not detect source file changes due to a lack of dependency on the .c source files. I have implemented a static pattern rule but that is not able to rebuild a single object file when a single source file changes. It will rebuild all of the changes.

I have the following:

```
ARCHITECTURE_DIR = arm
BUILD_DIR = build
OUTPUT_DIR = $(BUILD_DIR)/$(ARCHITECTURE_DIR)
SDK_DIR     = sdks/v4.0

SOURCE_FILES = \
  $(SDK_DIR)/alarm.c \
  ...

CSOURCES = $(filter %.c, $(SOURCE_FILES))

COBJS = $(addprefix $(OUTPUT_DIR)/,$(CSOURCES:.c=.o))
all: PROLOGUE $(COBJS)
  $(LD) $(COBJS) -o ...
```

Previously, the file had the following:

```
$(COBJS): %.o:
  @echo 'Building $(notdir $(@:%.o=%.c))...'
  @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $(filter %$(@:$(OUTPUT_DIR)/%.o=%.c),$(CSOURCES)) > /dev/null \
```

But this does not have a dependency on the .c files and thus does not recognize changes made and rebuild. I do not want to clean any time I make a source change. I changed it to the following:

```
COBJS = $(CSOURCES:.c=.o)

$(COBJS): %.o: %.c
    @echo 'Building $(notdir $(@:%.o=%.c))...'
    @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $(addprefix $(OUTPUT_DIR)/,$@) $< > /dev/null \
```

But this causes it to get rebuilt every time since the object files are getting put into a different directory. Is there a way to make it such that it can find these object files and not rebuilt if necessary?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: the posted make file contains: `COBJS = $(addprefix $(OUTPUT_DIR)/,$(CSOURCES:.c=.o))` However, there is no macro named: `CSOURCES`

Comment: OT: when defining a macro, the use of `=` results in the macro being re-evaluated every time it is referenced.  Suggest using: `:=` as that will eliminate the useless step of re-evaluating the macro

Comment: Ahh, sorry. CSOURCES is just a `$(filter %.c, $(SOURCE_FILES))` I'll edit it.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I fully understand where you want to store your different products but let's give it a try. From what you show of your Makefile I will assume that you want the object file corresponding to `sdks/v4.0/alarm.c` to be `build/arm/sdks/v4.0/alarm.o`. I will also assume that your target executable is `build/arm/sdks/v4.0/my_executable`.

1. You could rework your compilation pattern rule to use the real source and target files:

   ```
   $(OUTPUT_DIR)/%.o: %.c
       @echo 'Building $(@F)...'
       @mkdir -p $(@D)
       @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<
   ```

   Note that the recipe creates the destination directory before compiling (`mkdir -p ...`) and that it makes use of automatic variables (`$(@F)`, `$(@D)`) to get the basename and directory of the target.
2. You could use the real target file for your link rule to avoid useless rebuild; of course, you can also have a phony target used as an alias for the real target:

   ```
   EXEC := $(OUTPUT_DIR)/$(SDK_DIR)/my_executable
   ...
   .PHONY: all
   all: $(EXEC)
   ...    
   $(EXEC): PROLOGUE $(COBJS)
       $(LD) $(COBJS) -o $@
   ```

All in all, you could try something like:

```
ARCHITECTURE_DIR := arm
BUILD_DIR        := build
OUTPUT_DIR       := $(BUILD_DIR)/$(ARCHITECTURE_DIR)
SDK_DIR          := sdks/v4.0
SOURCE_FILES     := \
    $(SDK_DIR)/alarm.c \
    ...
CSOURCES         := $(filter %.c,$(SOURCE_FILES))
COBJS            := $(patsubst %.c,$(OUTPUT_DIR)/%.o,$(CSOURCES))
EXEC             := $(OUTPUT_DIR)/$(SDK_DIR)/my_executable

.PHONY: all
all: $(EXEC)

$(EXEC): PROLOGUE $(COBJS)
    $(LD) $(COBJS) -o $@

$(OUTPUT_DIR)/%.o: %.c
    @echo 'Building $(@F)...'
    @mkdir -p $(@D)
    @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
```